# paypal digital goods integration how to enable pay as guest?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, payment, credit-card

Hi i'm using paypal integration wizard to do digital goods checkout (PHP).
https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/

It should support both paypal payment and non-paypal payment(buy as a guest->credit card). in the wizard, it set payment option directly to paypal : $PaymentOption = "PayPal";

is there any way to enable paypal direct checkout as a guest? or do i need to add credit card api myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the receiving account.
In order to have Guest Checkout, the receiver needs to be a Premier Verified or Business Verified account.
(Verified = linked to a bank account).

If you don't meet that condition, PayPal will only give the buyer the option to log in or create an account.

Comment: but it should be able to test in sandbox, right? i'm wondering is there any coding part this digital goods wizard generated code  missing

Comment: It should work in sandbox. Again, you have to make sure that when you create your test receiver accounts, that you add both a bank account and a credit card. Make sure that you are using the pre-configured account option.  Manually created accounts in the sandbox are very flaky.