# paypal digital goods doesn't show option of "buy as a guest"

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [paypal digital goods integration how to enable pay as guest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774223/paypal-digital-goods-integration-how-to-enable-pay-as-guest)

i'm using paypal php wizard  `(https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/)` to generate code to handle digital goods payment. but how come there is no option of "buy as a guest" (i.e pay by credit card directly)?

Answer (score 2):

1. You must add the following item to the SetExpressCheckout method to enable this option on the live site:

   SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole

Comment: Guest checkout is available in Sandbox.

Comment: @Robert, yes, i've added that line, but still nothing happen

Comment: this is the piece i was missing

Comment: This was my solution too, thanks! it should be marked as accepted.